# Using Bootstrap rows and colums in javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/REST_API/api/post/read.php', function(data) {
    data.forEach(obj => {
        $( ".monsterlist" ).append("<div class='card' style='width:400px;'>"); 
        $( ".monsterlist" ).append("<img class='card-img-top' src='img/monster_img/"+ obj.monster_img+".png' style='width:200px;height:200px;'>"); 
        console.log(obj.monster_img);
        $( ".monsterlist" ).append("<div class='card-body'>"); 
        $( ".monsterlist" ).append("<h4 class'card-title'>"+obj.monster_name+"</h4>"); 
        $( ".monsterlist" ).append("<p class='card-text'>"+obj.monster_type+"</p>"); 
        $( ".monsterlist" ).append("</div></div>");
    });
});
```

Hello Guys. I play around with my own APIs. Everything works but now I try to output this in 3 rows each.

But I have no clue how to do it that I makes a new row after 3 objects. I tried a lot but nothing works. Maybe someone can help me :) I tried it like here [enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp)

Comment: What is your expected output ? Do you want to have 3 columns per row ?

Comment: `forEach` also passes index along with element. You can use the index to check for every third object. First do something like this `data.forEach((obj, index) =>`  . And then `if(index%3 ===0)`.

Comment: yes the expected output is 3 columns per row instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap supports automatic breaking of columns, just use col-4 (max per displayed row is always 12) as class for each column element you create.

You could use something like this inside the function call:

```
let card = `
<div class="card col-4" style='width:400px;'>
  <img class='card-img-top' src='img/monster_img/${obj.monster_img}.png' style='width:200px;height:200px;'>
  <div class='card-body'>
    <h4 class'card-title'>${obj.monster_name}</h4>
    <p class='card-text'>${obj.monster_type}</p>
  </div>
</div>
`;
$(".monsterlist").append(card);
```

Reference for Template Strings: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

The jQuery `$(node).append()` appends everything to the node you specify. Your node `.monsterlist` would've got all childnodes of the card-block, which would cause other issues. That's why i formated your code in this way.

`.monsterlist` also requires the class row.

```
<div class="monsterlist row"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use column breaks https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#column-breaks

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/REST_API/api/post/read.php', function(data) {
data.forEach((obj,index) => {
    $( ".monsterlist" ).append("<div class='card' style='width:400px;'>"); 
    $( ".monsterlist" ).append("<img class='card-img-top' src='img/monster_img/"+ obj.monster_img+".png' style='width:200px;height:200px;'>"); 
    console.log(obj.monster_img);
    $( ".monsterlist" ).append("<div class='card-body'>"); 
    $( ".monsterlist" ).append("<h4 class'card-title'>"+obj.monster_name+"</h4>"); 
    $( ".monsterlist" ).append("<p class='card-text'>"+obj.monster_type+"</p>"); 
    $( ".monsterlist" ).append("</div></div>");
    if(index%3===0 && index > 0){
       <!-- Force next columns to break to new line -->
       $( ".monsterlist" ).append("<div class="w-100"></div>");
    }
  });
});  
  </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: index%3 will result in wrong placements, first line will have 1 item, 2nd line 3... 3rd line 3... you have to use (index+1) %3. Because 0 % 3 = 0.

Comment: @Christopher Did you notice index > 0 condition?

Comment: yes and with this it will result in 4 entries within the first row.